# implement a simple inbox with notifications in yii

Tags: yii, notifications, inbox

I want to implement a simple inbox in yii. it reads messages from a database table and show it.

but i don't know how i should show read and unread messages in different styles and how i can implement a notification for new messages.

i searched a lot but only found some extensions and i don't want to use them.

it is so important to find how i can show unread messages in a different way

any initial idea would help me
a part of mailbox extension code :

```
public function actionInbox($ajax=null)
{
    $this->module->registerConfig($this->getAction()->getId());
    $cs =& $this->module->getClientScript();
    $cs->registerScriptFile($this->module->getAssetsUrl().'/js/mailbox.js',CClientScript::POS_END);
    //$js = '$("#mailbox-list").yiiMailboxList('.$this->module->getOptions().');console.log(1)';

    //$cs->registerScript('mailbox-js',$js,CClientScript::POS_READY);


    if(isset($_POST['convs']))
    {
        $this->buttonAction('inbox');
    }
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider( Mailbox::model()->inbox($this->module->getUserId()) );
    if(isset($ajax))
        $this->renderPartial('_mailbox',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
    else{
        if(!isset($_GET['Mailbox_sort']))
            $_GET['Mailbox_sort'] = 'modified.desc';

        $this->render('mailbox',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hows do you view look? How does your database look like? If you database knows when the message was read of if it was read can you not simply in the view do a simple check like if($model->read) { //change color } else { //do not change color } or something like that?

Comment: my database has a table for messages.in this table i store sender and receiver id, title,text of message and a field for read/unread which is 1 when the message is read. how can i show unread messages in a different way and how unread messages become read messages in controller? i do not have any view yet

Comment: Added a answer. To both the original question and the question "how unread messages become read messages in controller?". I however do not do so in the controller. To do so in the controller (the database you mean?) you simply update read to 1 while fetching the message from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the scripts things should be in the view. For you problem I would do something like

In the controller

```
$mailbox = Mailbox::model()->inbox($this->module->getUserId()); //I assume this returns the mailbox from that user? 

$this->renderPartial('_mailbox',compact('mailbox ')); //compact is the same as array('mailbox'=>$mailbox) so use whatever you prefer.
```

In the view I would simply do something like this

```
<?php foreach($mailbox->messages as $message):
     $class = ''; //order unread if you want to give both a different class name 
     if($message->read): //if this is true 
           $class = 'read'; 
     endif; ?>
     <div id='<?= $message->id ?>'class='message $class'> <!-- insert whatever info from the message --></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So now it will add the class read to every message that has been read. Then in CSS you can simply change it style.  I hope this is enough information? I use foreach(): endforeach; and if(): endif; in the view files, but you could use foreach() {}, but I prefer foreach, as it looks better combined with HTML.

EDIT about you second question, how do they become read. This you could do with JQUERY. example.

```
$(".message").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax {
        type:"POST",
        url: "controller/action/"+id; //the controller action that fetches the message, the Id is the action variable (ex: public function actionGetMessage($id) {})
        completed: function(data) {
            //data = the message information, you might do type: 'JSON' instead. Use it however you want it. 
            if(!$(this).hasClass("read"))
                $(this).addClass("read"); //give it the class read if it does not have it already
        }
    }
});
```

This simply gives the div the class read and it should look like the other items with the class read.